# Check whether or not a number is the sum of two squares in C

Tags: c, math

I need your help on this problem , I've been trying to solve it all day but I can't reach a solution.
I just started studying C so I apologize if it is a stupid question, however
I am only allowed to use:

- `if`
- `for`
- `do-while`
- `while`

statements to solve the problem.

I need to check whether or not a given number can be written as the sum of two squares, I do not need to know which are these two squares, and I do not need to analyze cases when the number is 0 or 1. What I've managed to build till now is:

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned int q = 1;
printf("Enter a number : \n");
scanf("%u", &x);
unsigned int j = sqrt(x - (q*q));
if (x != 1 && x != 0)
    for (q; (q*q) <= (x/2); q++)
        if ((x - (q*q)) == (j*j))
printf("Given number is sum of two squares");
```

This one sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, for example it does work for `65 (8^2+1^2)` and `90 (9^2+3^2)` but wouldn't work when I put 181 `(10^2+9^2)` and so on.. 
Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: So no return` or expression statements like `a = b;`? Sorry, that is not possible. YOur code already violates the constraints.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I can use expressions like a=b,

Comment: Yes, that's clear, as `while` etc. don't work without. But can you also use _expression-statements_?

Comment: Yes I can use those!

Comment: Note that a number N is a sum of 2 squares if and only if in the prime factorization of N, every prime of the form (4k+3) occurs an even number of times.

Comment: Please, post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve example.... don't post pieces of code... post an example tha runs out of the box and shows the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so here's pseudo code for a possible solution:

```
Input x;

int a;
int b;

for(a=0; a <= x; a++){

   for(b=a; b <= x; b++){

      if((a*a + b*b) == x){
         Output is_solution;
      }

   }

}
```

In the nested loop, `b` is assigned the value of `a` to avoid checking the same sum of squares more than once.

Converting this to C, should look like this:

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned int a;
unsigned int b;

printf("Enter a number : \n");
scanf("%u", &x);

for(a=0; a<=x; a++){
   for(b=a; b<=x; b++){
      if((a*a + b*b) == x){
         printf("Given number is sum of two squares");
      }
   }
}
```

I'm a bit rusted in C, hopefully it doesn't have any nasty errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried to compile it but looks like it prints "given number .." for every number i put

Comment: `sqrt(a)` calculates the square root of `a` not the square of `a`. And obviously every natural number is the sum of two square roots.

Comment: @chtz, you're right, my mistake, thanks. Tsurupeta, I've update my answer in case you want to give it a second try.

Comment: sorry @DavidNeto, i have the time to make a comment, but not today to write a complete solution to the problem.  But the idea is clear and good to be made as exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the calculation of `j` inside the `for` loop. Currently, you only calculate `j` for `q=1`.

I recommend putting the blocks of the loops and the `if` into braces. I.e.,

```
 if(condition)
 {
     // statements
 }
```

Comment: But I do not understand, if i only calculate J for q=1, how can the program find 90 (9^2+3^2) ?

Comment: For `x=90` you are computing `sqrt(90-1)=9.48....` which when stored as `int` is rounded down to 9.

Comment: Ah i see, so It should be something like this? 
 for (q; (q*q) <= (x/2); q++){
 j = sqrt(x - (q*q)) }
 if ((x - (q*q)) == (j*j))  {
printf("Given number is sum of two squares");}

Comment: @Tsurupeta close, but the `if` must be in the block of the `for` loop as well, of course.

Comment: Seems like it works now, finally, thank you very much! But one last question, sometimes J has the right value, but sometime it gives me a completely unexpected result, for example if i input 200 J is 1410, if I input 1000 J becomes 3026.. is there something wrong with my code?